# Initialize child class before parent class without composition / decorator

Tags: c++, c++11

Once again I need to do something like this -
I need to initialize first the vector, so I pass its data() address to the parent class.

```
#include <vector>

struct A{
    A(int *a) : a(a){}
    
    int *a;
};

struct B : A{
    B() : A( v.data() ){}
    
    std::vector<int> v { 1024 };
};

#include <cstdio>

int main(){
    B b;
    b.v[55] = 5;

    printf("%d\n", b.a == b.v.data() );
    printf("%d\n", b.a[55]);
    printf("%d\n", b.v[55]);
}
```

Problem here is that the vector is initialized **after** parent class and `v.data()` contains junk. I am even surprised this compiles.

I know I can use composition / decorator for this or protected member `setPtr(int *a)`, but I wonder if there is another way to do it.

Please do not comment about raw pointers. This is just an example for dependencies between parent and child classes.

Comment: you should indicate what can change and waht cannot. `v.data()` you cannot use, but you can use `v`s adress or a reference to `v` to get `data` later, once `v` is constructed. What is the actual aim? Why does `A` need the pointer ?

Comment: I assume the base member is actually `private`?

Comment: May I ask why would the base class need to know or get anything from a subclass ? sounds like bad design.

Comment: @TonyTannous Dunno, `B` could be an implementation of an interface that presents a pointer to "some data"; not mad. But done a bit strangely here

Comment: class A is ArenaAlocator, class B supply the buffer, so I have the buffer and the allocator into single object.

Comment: If A is supposed to know stuff about its derived classes, it might be a fitting candidate for the CRTP.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using a raw pointer here, since it's a non-owning pointer. The memory is owned by the vector.

Comment: seems I will refactor the class hard way - create buffer class and pass into the c-tor (via template).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Base classes are constructed first by design. No way around it. However, you can introduce a second base class and inherit from your base classes in desired order of initialization.

```cpp
struct a
{
    int x;
    a(int x) : x(x) {};
};

struct b
{
    int *px;
    b(int* px) : px(px) {};
};

struct derived : a, b
{
public:
    derived(int x_) : a(x_), b(&x) {};
};
```

Comment: This won't work. x is a local variable in the derived constructor, and ends scope when the constructor returns. The b instance would have a pointer to junk. You should pass &this->A::x instead.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 Thank you, I definitely have some bad habits when it comes to argument names. I corrected the source by throwing in some underscores.

Comment: It is the [Base-from-Member idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Base-from-Member). boost provide [base_from_member](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/base_from_member.html).

Answer (score 2):

Why not delegate initialization for A to some function other than the constructor?

```
#include <vector>

struct A{
    A() : a(nullptr) {}
    void init(int* i_a) {
        a = i_a;
    }
    
    int *a;
};

struct B : A{
    B() : A(), v(1024) {
        init(v.data());
    }
    
    std::vector<int> v;
};

#include <cstdio>

int main(){
    B b;
    b.v[55] = 5;

    printf("%d\n", b.a == b.v.data() );
    printf("%d\n", b.a[55]);
    printf("%d\n", b.v[55]);
}
```

Also, why are you using `printf` in C++? It's rather unsafe. Use `std::cout` instead. Contrary to common belief it's actually not that much slower than C stdio, if you handle it well, and we're not sure that I/O speed is even a problem for your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, no offence, but I hate "init". then what the c-tor actually do? `printf` - quick, short easy to use, at least when you are using simple types like `int`

Comment: C-tor does nothing, initializes it to a blank state. The effective c-tor would be the init function. `std::cout` -- quick, shorter, easier to use (`std::cout << a`), more type-safe and less need to remember and debug formatting specs. :)

Comment: And then what if programmer forgot to call `init()`? You are correct for iostream.

Comment: @Nick there is already a tight coupling between the base and the derived by your design. I don't see a big problem with calling `init`

Comment: @Nick and what if programmer forgot to initialize your vector `v` with `{ 1024 }`? There's always a possibility for a programmer to use a library incorrectly, this not much more than others. Just remember to call init() soon after constructing.

Comment: Shame on me, but if `init` is protected method, and is invoke inside the c-tor of derived class, then this is exactly what I need and is easy and readable

Answer (score 2):

Not suggesting this as solution, but it might give a hint to an actual solution. You cannot use members of the derived class in the base class constructor. You can, however, use references or pointers to members of the derived while constructing the base. You only need to take care to only dereference them after the derived is fully constructed. For example this is "ok":

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct A{
    A(std::vector<int>* p) : p(p){}
    std::vector<int>* p;
};

struct B : A{
    B() : A( &v ){} // <- fine as long as A only stores the pointer
    std::vector<int> v { 1024 };
};

int main(){
    B b;
    b.v[55] = 5;
    std::cout << (b.p == &b.v) << "\n";
    std::cout << (*b.p)[55];
}
```

Comment: This make parent class to be "tied" to the vector. but probably if it is templatized it will be able to pass another kind of buffers, not std::array directly, but something like C++20 span or view (not sure of correct name)

Comment: @Nick there are ways around that, I just didn't want to change more than necessary, and don't understand your use case, allocators is beyond me

Answer (score 2):

I went for the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

template <typename T>
struct Base {
  int* raw_ptr = nullptr;   
  void Supply() {
    (static_cast<T*>(this))->Supply();
  }
};

struct Derived : public Base<Derived> {
  std::vector<int> v { 1024 }; 
  void Supply() {
    raw_ptr = v.data();
  }
};


template<typename T>
void SupplyBuffer(Base<T>* b) {
  b->Supply();
}

int main()
{
    Derived b;
    SupplyBuffer(&b);
    b.v[55] = 5;    
    printf("%d\n", b.raw_ptr == b.v.data() );
    printf("%d\n", b.raw_ptr[55]);
    printf("%d\n", b.v[55]);
    return 0;
}
```